# To fetch value with comma separated ID with Join two tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables shown as below

product_category Table

```
╔═════════════╦═════════════════╗
║ category_id ║    parent_id    ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 1           ║ 8,7             ║
║ 2           ║ 8               ║
╚═════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

product_category_description Table

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╦═════════╗
║ id      ║category_id║ name    ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═════════╣
║ 1       ║   1       ║ Test    ║
║ 2       ║   2       ║ Test1   ║
║ 3       ║   3       ║ Test2   ║
║ 4       ║   7       ║ Test3   ║
║ 5       ║   8       ║ Test4   ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╩═════════╝
```

I want output shown below

```
    ╠══════════╬═══════════════╣
    ║ 1        ║ Test4, Test3  ║
    ║ 2        ║ Test4         ║
    ╚══════════╩═══════════════╝
```

I have tried below query but not working:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(b.category_name) cat_name 
FROM  product_category  a 
INNER JOIN product_category_description b 
ON FIND_IN_SET(a.parent_id, b.category_id) > 0 
GROUP   BY b.category_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below query i checked with my database

```
SELECT a.category_id,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.name)
FROM product_category_description  AS b
INNER JOIN `product_category` as a 
ON  FIND_IN_SET(b.category_id,a.parent_id)
GROUP BY category_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Everthing is right except the `group by` field

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(b.category_name) cat_name 
FROM  
product_category  a 
INNER JOIN 
product_category_description b 
ON FIND_IN_SET(a.parent_id, b.category_id) > 0 
GROUP BY 
a.category_id
```

Comment: its return values like

1 Test4,Test4,Test3,Test3

Comment: If you need distinct category names then you need to use `DISTINCT` eg GROUP_CONCAT(distinct b.category_name)

Comment: distinct returns single value,not comma separated

Comment: I am afraid this will work GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(b.category_name))